# How to move whole layout above the soft keyboard in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I, want to implement functionality like whenever my soft-keyboard get open's my whole layout will get above that keyboard in android. I already google it and find some suitable answers related to it. But it's not working as per my expectations.

I have added this in my manifest: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize". But it only do limited layout above the keyboard. I want my whole layout will above the keyboard.

Below are some image for better representation...

As you can see in image my keyboard is coming over the layout. I want that my whole layout means till the Register Button will come above the soft-keyboard.

[image: As you can see in image my keyboard is coming over the layout. I want that my whole layout means till the Register Button will come above the soft-keyboard.]

Below is My XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Welcome,"
            android:textAlignment="center"
           />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Register to Get Your Grocery Store Online"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/storeName"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLabel"
           >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Store Name"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/storeLocationPinCode"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLabel"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Store Location PinCode"
                 />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/storeCity"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLabel"
           >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Store City"
               />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/storeState"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLabel"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Store State"
               />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/storeAddress"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLabel"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Store Address"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/minimumAmount"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLabel"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/deliveryCharges"
            style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewLabel"

            >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Delivery Charges"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/registerMerchant"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Register"
            android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
           />


    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, I think `adjustPan` is better than `adjustResize`, it will push up all your layout.

`adjustResize` depends on layout parameters, if you're using `ConstraintLayout`, views only constraint bottom to bottom of parent will be pushed up.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

`<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>`

to your activity in manifest file